# Replace values in angular with ngif or other

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a GET Request that is returning tasks:

```
"tasks": [
    {
      "partner_id": 1,
      "title": "aa",
      "description": "dddd",
      "priority": "High",
    }]
```

and i have another GET Request representing the values of the partner.

```
"partners": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "str"
    }]
```

When implementing the view, and doing a ngfor on the tasks, i'd like to replace the task.partner_id for the real name on the partner.

```
//getting the id of the task.partner_id and represent the partner.value
<span><span class="bold">For</span> {{task.partner_id}}</span>
```

[image]

Instead of 1 being the partner name equivalent to id: 1.

How can I do this without manipulating the request that is coming from the API?

UPDATE:
I've used the solutions suggested by @errorau and @Clint

```
getParentValue(parents, parentId) {
  return Object.keys(parents).find(key => parents[key] === parentId);
}
```

and it worked fine, i'm rendering the right values on the frontend. but right now i'm receiving an error:
[image]

Comment: in this case are you are wanting to use the value property from partners when the id property is 1?

Comment: You could use a pipe to "find" the equivalent value in the partners array, or just create a new object from both.

Comment: Try this `partners.find((p) => p.id === task.partner_id).value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manipulating your api you can write basic a funtion for get parent value like

```
<span><span class="bold">For</span> {{getTask(task.partner_id)}}</span>
```

you can write this function like that

```
  function getTask(id){
    return partners.find((p) => p.id === id).value
}
```

Comment: your solution worked, i'm rendering the right values.
But right now i'm receveing an error: 

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: @cristianOliveira i updated my answer could you please try again...

Answer (score 1):

in html

```
<span><span class="bold">For</span> {{getPartnerValue(task.partner_id)}}</span>
```

in the component.ts file

```
getPartnerValue(id){
 return this.partners.filter(partner => +partner.id === +id)[0].value;
}
```

Comment: your solution worked, i'm rendering the right values.
But right now i'm receveing an error: 

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You could construct the view model that combines both of them in the component file.

`component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
const tasks = [
  {
    partner_id: 1,
    title: 'aa',
    description: 'dddd',
    priority: 'High',
  },
];

const partners = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'str',
  },
];

// build the view model that combine both data
this.models = tasks.reduce((prev, task) => {
  const matchedPartner = partners.find(
    (partner) => partner.id === task.partner_id
  );

  return prev.concat({
    ...task,
    partner_name: matchedPartner ? matchedPartner.value : '', // add a new field to store partner name, if not found, default to empty string
  });
}, []);
}
```

`component.html`

```html
<div *ngFor="let model of models">
    <h1>{{ model.partner_name }}</h1>
</div>
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-65305553?file=src/app/app.component.ts